# Symfony2: use http cache

Tags: symfony, http, caching

Within Symfony2, I try to use http caching for few ajax calls that return always the same content in a day.

My controller's code finishes with:

```
    $response = new JsonResponse($data);
    $response->setPublic();
    $response->setExpires(new \DateTime("+1 hour"));
    $response->setMaxAge(3600);
    return $response;
```

In the response (from Firefox or IE11) I can find the expected headers. But it always return a 200 code (OK) instead of 304 (not modified). This mean that the server always generate the response, whereas my goal is to underload my server.

I also tried to use the @Cache annotation with the same result.

How to make it work?

Comment: What are you using the perform the AJAX request? Some libraries add no-cache query strings to AJAX requests.

Comment: I use Jquery, trying to set {cache: true} in the $.ajax parameter doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

You can make symfony return a 304 response by using the AppCache kernel (a reverse proxy written in PHP) in your app.php

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel); // Uncomment or add this line to app.php
```

On production, you should consider using a real reverse proxy server, like Varnish.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html

Answer (score 2):

I Successfully cache your example response by adding the `LastModified` header on the response.
I Do the following two things:

**1. Configure Symfony as Reverse proxy**

I Create a custom environment, in the web folder, i create a file named app_cache. As described [here in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#symfony-reverse-proxy) as follow:

```
#web/app_cache.php
<?php

// web/app.php
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
// wrap the default AppKernel with the AppCache one
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**2. Add the Last Modified header on the response**

I use this controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/cache-me", name="cacheme")
 */
public function cacheMeAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = array("hello" => "symfony");

    $response = new JsonResponse($data);
    $response->setPublic();
    $response->setExpires(new \DateTime("+1 hour"));
    $response->setLastModified(new \DateTime("-1 hour"));

    return $response;
}
```

**3. Test**

I clear the cache for prod environment (`app/cache -e=prod`) and make two request with my browser to the url:

> http://sf.localhost/app_cache.php/cache-me

The first return a 200 Ok and the second 304 not modified

Hope this help

Comment: That is OK for me with the setLastModified, but only for public cache (not private). That is already cool!

Comment: Hi @Rolintocour you are welcome! Of course, your question was about public cache. Please consider to upvote and/or accept my answer if you consider it useful

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be cache your data manually using `cache` service in your controller before doing your  usual stuff like querying database and fetch content just check if there is already exist cached data then send this data to user else do your usual stuff and save fresh data in cache. `JsonResponse` class takes second parameter for status code here you can manually set 304

```
$cache = $this->container->get( 'cache' );
$cache_key = 'trafficfeed';
    if ( $cache->contains( $cache_key ) ) {
        $data  = $cache->fetch($cache_key  );
        /** here $data is a cached data */
        /** Response::HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED => 304*/
        $response = new JsonResponse($data,Response::HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED);
        return $response;
    }
/** Fetch fresh data and save in cache */
$cache->save( $cache_key, $data, 3600 );
$response = new JsonResponse($data);
```

For cache service you need to define it in your config

```
services:

    cache:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\PhpFileCache
        arguments: [%kernel.cache_dir%]
```